# How to restrict a IIS7 WCF service to a specific IP

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, wcf

I'm trying to enable one IP adress from accessing and consuming my WCF service. How can i do it ? is there a way to do it with IIS ?

Comment: I think this question was already answered in this [community post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722008/can-i-setup-an-ip-filter-for-a-wcf-service/803813#803813)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You need to install the Web-IP-Security feature for IIS.

From PowerShell:

```
Install-WindowsFeature Web-IP-Security
```

[image: Description]

Using IIS Manager navigate to the specific service you are trying to restrict.

- Select IP Address and Domain Restrictions.
- Click "Edit Feature Settings" on the far right in the Actions menu
- Set "Access for unspecified clients" to Deny, Click OK
- Click "Add Allow Entry" on the far right in the Actions menu
- Enter the IP address that you want to allow, Click OK